# Disabling UAA default Web UI application

Tags: cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa

I want to disable the **UAA**'s default Web UI application and use a custom one instead so I can show more informations to the user and give him the ability to perform more tasks. UAA default web application allow very basic operations like updating the email or password only.

**UAA** is available at a domain like: https://account.example.com, I want to display a custom application when the user goes to this endpoint.

The documentation states ([here](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/api/uaa/version/74.17.0/index.html#external-login-server)):

> The UAA provides endpoints that facilitate the use of an external
>   login server. A server that handles the UI for browser based actions.

That was mentioned [here](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa/blob/7ca91e2580b394937f3bae8d18187c198cdf62e9/docs/UAA-APIs.rst#trusted-authentication-from-login-server) as well.

How this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this script which will unpack a .war, add in your customized templates and resources, and pack up the .war again

https://github.com/starkandwayne/quick-uaa-deployment-cf/blob/master/bin/customize-uaa-war

Helpful?

Comment: Is there a way to have a customized UI without using a non stock UAA? like putting it behind a reverse proxy?

Comment: Im using their official docker image https://hub.docker.com/r/cfidentity/uaa

Comment: @KarimH perhaps you'll need to create your own docker image that bundles your own .war; or an overlay docker image that performs the `customize-uaa-war` script during startup to mutate the .war to include your theme changes.

Comment: Is it a good idea to create a fork and build a docker image from it?